# SQL query to override content of column when matched column

Tags: sql

Please who can help with this scenario?

I have two tables, both they have a common column `ID`, and Table 1 has a column `Title`. Normally I should update the content of this `Title` column for some ID, but since the table was already in use somewhere else, it wasn't a good idea to change data directly in Table 1.

That's why I created a new table table 2, which hold only the `Title` that must be changed associated with these ID that must be changed.

Now I am trying to get these updated titles from table 2, when there is a matching `ID` in table 1, otherwise show only the contents of table 1.

The result should be something like that but without using If statements.

```
__ID__ Title 
|         | |      |
|         | |      |
```

Comment: Where's your data? Why `IF` not allowed? Is `CASE` okay?

Comment: Which database do you really use? I doubt it is both MySQL and Oracle.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: I am ising Oracle Database

Comment: Because i am using i am storing the results into a View, and i don't want to create a procedure for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to this new table and `COALESCE()` function to say "If there is data in the new table, use it, otherwise use the data in the existing table" . Something like:

```
SELECT t1.id, COALESCE(t2.title, t1.title) as title
FROM t1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```